# Tweaking INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to change some old deprecated code on how items are saved in my game. The current method is deleting all items, then inserting all items, then inserting equipment (child table of the items). It has a pretty big performance impact and I was wondering if changing the INSERTS to INSERTS ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE would have a noticeable impact on performance.

If it does, then I have a follow-up question. My plan is to load the items in with their original **inventoryitemid** and use that as the key to save with later.

The issue is when executing this following statement:

```
INSERT INTO inventoryitems (inventoryitemid, itemid) VALUES (?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...
```

may miss some conditions. What I would like is for MySQL to INSERT if it doesn't exist with the default value (auto increment), otherwise UPDATE. At the moment new items are generated with an inventoryitemid at 0 since keys are generated on INSERT anyways.

**tl;dr**: I need a way to INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE without having the inventoryitemid beforehand (since new items are generated in-game with inventoryitemid of 0). At the moment I have to specify what the inventoryitemid is beforehand and I might not have access to that information.

First goal and issue

1. Try to insert a new item that doesn't exist in the database without having the inventoryitemid beforehand.
2. Item isn't inserted into the database with the next incremented db value.

Second goal (no issue)

1. Attempting to insert item into database with an existing inventory itemid
2. Database updates the item in the database successfully (yay!)

Trying out solution: Inserting value with NULL to try to trigger the autoincrement

Comment: Sounds like REPLACE instead INSERT could save your problem (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replace.html)

Comment: Is `itemid` unique?

Comment: @TadejP `REPLACE` needs the same uniqueness criteria as `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

Comment: @KarlLaurentiusRoos it should be unique

Comment: @Barmar Is there any work around?

Comment: If you don't have a unique column, how is it supposed to know if it needs to insert a new row or update an existing row? It doesn't make sense to do this if you don't have some other unique column?

Comment: @Barmar At the moment the inventoryitemid is the only unique column. Do you think this is poor database design that is causing me issues. I don't know how to get around it in general.

Comment: Does your source of data know whether the rows are new or old? If you provide `inventoryitemid = NULL`, when inserting, it will not be a duplicate key, so it will insert and do an auto-increment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're inserting a new row, specify `inventoryitemid = NULL`. This will create a new row because it's not a duplicate key, and it will auto-increment the `inventoryitemid`.

After you insert a new item like this, you can use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` to get the `inventoryitemid` that was assign to it. Then you can send that to the game code so it will know that the new item has this ID. It can then use this ID in future updates, instead of sending `NULL`.

When you're modifying an existing row, specify the value of its `inventoryitemid`. Then the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` code will replace it instead of inserting a new row.

Comment: That part works. What I'm concerned with is when a new item is generated in game it won't know its inventoryitemid. So when I go to add the information in the query I don't know what to feed it because Java will instantiate the new inventoryitemid to 0, which is problematic. What I want is if it's new I want it inserted, otherwise updated if that makes sense.

Comment: When you create a new item, you have to send the `inventoryitemid` back to the game code so that it will be able to update it in the future.

Comment: What should I do then because this is pretty costly? The item is created inside the game when a monster dies and drops it. Since I don't want to save each time a player encounters an item, I save when they log out, etc. During this time, the original solution was just to delete all then reinsert without worrying about updating. 

But now since I want to update, I bring in the inventoryitemid but that also means I need a way to insert new items into the database and generate a key.

Comment: Why is that a problem? When you save, all the new items get `NULL` because they don't have an ID yet. All the old items have their ID.

Comment: You could also just use an `if` statement in the Java code. If it knows the ID, it performs an `UPDATE`, if it doesn't it performs `INSERT`.

Comment: But the issue is I want the new items to get an ID. Inserting NULL won't do that, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143452/discussion-between-jonathan-nguyen-and-barmar).